# Jelly Bean resource Usage

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, ram

I have a phone with 512MB of ram. The company has launched the Jelly Bean update for the phone. Currently my phone is running Android ICS 4.0.4 which has alot of lag and frameloss issues, So I am thinking to update to JB. However I am concerned about the memory usage of JB. 
So my question is:

Whether JB uses more ram than ICS?

Answer (score 1):

Jelly Bean uses pretty much the same amount of RAM. There's not much of a difference.

Performance-wise, Jelly Bean is much better. It will even make phones with 512MB RAM feel smooth, with some lag still, cause you know.... 512MB RAM, but it should feel much better than ICS.

Answer (score 0):

Jellybean will use the same amount of RAM like ICS. But one thing, Jellybean using "BUTTER PROJECT", a project from google that beats lag..
So basically, the update from ICS to Jellybean will give much faster and smooth experience..

Answer (score -3):

512 MB RAM is too little for gingerbread, let alone ICS. And you're thinking of jelly bean. Jelly bean is meant for phones with around 2 GB RAM.  Ofcourse Jelly bean uses a whole lot RAM than ICS.  You should downgrade to gingerbread or possibly froyo so that phone works well without any lag and freezeups.  Even if you downgrade to gingerbread, you should not install more apps from google play because 512 is just enough to run gingerbread without more apps. BTW, why did you buy a 512MB RAM only phone? Should have purchased at least 1 GB RAM phone. Android is becoming a heavy resource consuming system and 1 GB is minimum the way applications are being launched. Its becoming more and more bloated by the day